# Laravel Sanctum Vue.js - How to check if session is expired

Tags: laravel, vue.js, authentication, session

I'm starting up a learning project with Laravel, VueJS. I'm using Sanctum cookie based.
I have got the authentication working with the help of several tutorials, but none of the tutorials covers the piece of checking if your session is expired or not. The tutorials that where covering it where using LocalStorage, and what I red about is that you should avoid LocalStorage.
I'm looking for a simple possibility to check if a user is still authenticated and if not, then redirect them to the login page, or even better, show a modal to login and go further where they are.

22 jan 2021 Still haven't got he answer :(

I'm fairly new to VueJS, Vuex and so on :)

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, its what I've been using so far. Its not very ideal but works out fine so far until I can make it better.

Put this in `App.vue` created method

```
// each call needs csrf token to work, so we call this on app load once.
axios.get(axios.rootURL + '/sanctum/csrf-cookie').catch(() => {
  alert('Something went wrong, Contact admin <br> ErrorCode: csrf')
})

// this part is not necessary, you may adapt as required
// let isLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn') ? true : false
// this.setIsLoggedIn(isLoggedIn)

axios.interceptors.request.use(
  config => {
    return config
  },
  error => {
    return Promise.reject(error)
  }
)

// this is the actual part you need, here we check on each call
// if we get error 401 which is unauthenticated we redirect to login. That's it
axios.interceptors.response.use(
  response => {
    return response
  },
  error => {
    if (error.response.status === 401) {
      this.$router.push({ name: 'login' })
      localStorage.removeItem('isLoggedIn')
      this.setIsLoggedIn(false)
    }

    return Promise.reject(error)
  }
)
```

Comment: I think this is a nice solution. I implemented it and it works fine. Can you explain why you think it is not ideal?

Comment: Hi @Dawied, This approach works but, there is one problem. Say you open the app and logged in, after some inactivity, the session might get destroyed. So if a user then clicks into a new private page that has an API call, the interceptor would catch 401 error and redirect. Thing is, all the session checking should be in practice happen before loading the new private page, not after showing the whole empty page and redirecting back to login. weird UX. That at least was the problem I had with this implementation, hope you would handle such scenarios if need be.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Abdul Rehman. I combine the axios interceptor with a router guard. So the interceptor is a fail safe. Also maybe a check on the user session at some starting point in the app could prevent the expired session.